# Replace spacing with another character with function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make function `changeSpacesWith`,
which accepts 2 parameters namely `str` and `to`. The function will replace the space in `str` with the value we pass it via the `to` parameter and returns that value.

Example:

- input: `changeSpacesWith ('Steve Fox', '-')`
  output: 'Steve-Fox'
- input: `changeSpacesWith ('Sergei Dragunov', '+')`
  output: 'Sergei + Dragunov'

```
function changeSpacesWith (str, to) {
  // Code disini
  str = str.replace(/ /g, `-`);

};

changeSpacesWith ('Steve Fox', '-');
```

What should i do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split(' ').join('-')
```

`split` returns an array where each element is divided by the delimiter passed in and the `join` reforms the string using your chosen character.

Answer (score 0):

This function will convert single or multiple spaces into a single character.

```js
function changeSpacesWith (str, to) {
  // Code disini
  str = str.replace(/\s+|\s/g, to);
  return str
};

console.log(changeSpacesWith('Steve Fox', '-'));
console.log(changeSpacesWith('Steve     Fox', '+'));
```